# Python, Pandas, pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

The file I'm loading using Python, Pandas has too many lines than I need.

```py
df = pd. read_csv(path, sep=';')
```

[image]

[image]

The file contains observations that first count to the beginning of the day to the end of the day, then from the end of the day to the beginning, then from the beginning of the day to the end of the day (mathematical conditions, hence this approach).

The final thing I want to do is to extract only the header and the last part of the data (1/3 of the data) from the file already. I have no idea how to cut out the first two conversions of the day.

I tried at first to cut the beginning through the index, but there are not always as many calculations in the day, so the solution would have to pull by columns: YY='2022' and MM='9' and DD='1' and hh='0' and mm='0' and ss='0'. But only after the third time finding a row with such values.

Comment: Please add your data as text, not as images, and please add your code. Maybe have a look at this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Please take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: Can you load the whole thing into memory and then filter? If yes, it is much easier to solve your problem.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(path,sep=";",skiprows=range(1,5762))`. Start the range at 1 to keep the top row for headers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what you need help with exactly. Please read [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
#Filter to the data that matches the date time criteria
filtered_df = df[(df['YY'] == '2022') & (df['MM'] == '9')& (df['DD'] == '1')& (df['hh'] == '0')& (df['mm'] == '0')& (df['ss'] == '0')]

#Extract every third row of data
result = filtered_df.iloc[::3]
```